# printing component before it is rendered to DOM with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a bunch of inputs and on submit click I would like to print a component that contains the user inputs. I'm using a package react-to-print but I could not figure out how to actually print the component without it showing on the DOM. Is there a way I can reference to that component without displaying it on the DOM?

Comment: This module uses `window.print()` (there is no other way), and that command prints whatever is visible in the current window. So my guess is that what you're looking for is impossible without showing the component at least while the printing dialog is open.

Comment: is there an option of doing it without this package and achieve my result?

Comment: The package doesn't matter; my comment applies to printing websites in general.

Comment: So how for example ecoms sites can generate pdf or print invoice for example without it showing on DOM?

Comment: Generating a PDF is an entirely different matter; it is generated by the backend and delivered to the browser as download. The browser can also display. then print the PDF of course. You say you can print the invoice from the browser without it being visible? How exactly would that work?